# useSWR returning undefined data without making a request to backend

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, swr

I am trying to fetch user detail from backend and display profile page using swr and axios but useSWR returning undefined data and error without making request to backend can anyone tell what i'm doing wrong here?

here is my code for fetching user detail

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import useSWR from "swr";
import axiosInstance from "../axios";

export const userDetailContext = createContext();

export default function UserDetailContextProvider({ children }) {
  console.log("running user detail context");
  const router = useRouter();
  const { username } = router.query;
  const fetcher = async (arg) =>
    axiosInstance
      .get(arg)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((err) => err);

  const { data, error } = useSWR(`${username}/`, fetcher);
  console.log(data, error);
  return (
    <userDetailContext.Provider value={{ data, error }}>
      {children}
    </userDetailContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

localhost/[username] =>

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";

import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar";
import ProfileComp from "../../components/profile/ProfileComp";
import withAuth from "../../components/HigherOrderComps/withAuth";
import UserDetailContextProvider from "../../context/UserDetaillContext";

function Profile() {
  return (
    <UserDetailContextProvider>
      <Head>
        <title>Profile</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <ProfileComp />
    </UserDetailContextProvider>
  );
}
```

error i'm getting

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

> Uncaught Error: Failed to parse src "http://localhost:8000undefined" on `next/image`, if using relative image it must start with a leading slash "/" or be an absolute URL (http:// or https://)

Comment: _"useSWR returning undefined data and error"_ - What error are you seeing?

Comment: It's giving error for Image component since it cannot make valid url for image because of undefined data.

Comment: But is the `axios` request triggering any errors? Do you see the request being successful in the devtools Network tab?

Comment: no its not triggering any errors.

Comment: it's rendering "UserDetailContextProvider" component but that component returns undefined data and undefined error